# iMac 10,1 (2019) frozen still after login

Tags: finder, imac, startup

I have an iMac a friend lent me to try and fix it. I have tried several things but I'm not too educated on apple soft/hardware. Let me explain the problems of this computer:

- You're able to launch the computer and login to it.
- After that, finder launches immediately, as well as google chrome and safari. The three of them crash and are unusable.
- Restarting finder leads to it crashing on startup again.
- I can access other settings via spotlight, but the rest is unusable.
- Searching for updates fails, it tells me internet isn't connected wether I'm connected via WiFi or cable. The connection does work on every other device.

And this is what I've tried so far:

- Tried deleting apple.finder.plist
- Tried booting the recovery program via command + R, it doesn't work (other startup commands like command + d or safemode works, but not the recovery)
- Tried booting from usb rocking a dmg of Mac OSX High Sierra, the computer doesn't recognize the usb (I've set it up to be bootable with Transmac on windows)

I'm running out of ideas on how to fix the computer. Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: What about Safe Boot? Have you tried that? Hold shift at startup till the Apple logo appears. Can you get into System Preferences long enough to create another user account?

Comment: I tried to create another user account, but it wouldn't let me in the setttings because clicking the lock would make it crash. I managed to create another user via the console, but the problem persists across the users.
Using Safe Boot leads to the same problems. Finder is crashed and won't work at all.
I want to boot from a High Sierra USB to install it on the computer. How do you create a bootable USB for mac on a windows system?

Comment: I have never done that but seen a few people here who have done that successfully. I think you are on the right track though: install a fresh OS (reformat the HD first, **after** you validate a recent backup!) and if the issues persist it is likely hardware. If that clears it up it was a badly corrupted macOS installation.